# Python Requests - downloading a .py file from GitHub

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-requests

I'm trying to use Requests to load a .py file from a GitHub directory. The .py file starts like this (I guess it's a dictionary?):

```
colors = {

    "1234": {
        "shade": [1, 2, 3]
        }
    }
```

I use the following code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://raw.github.com/example/example1/master/scripts/colors.py')
```

I would like r to be a variable or a dictionary, so that I can easily look for some specific strings inside. However, when I print r I don't get a .py file, but there are also signs like \r\n etc. How can I read this file properly?

```
r.text

>>> 'colors = {\r\n\r\n    "1234": {\r\n        "shade": [1, 2, 3]}\r\n}\r\n'
```

At the end I would like to create a dictionary, where for "shade" I obtain all values. So first I would need to search r for the word "shade".

I will be thankful for any suggestions and solutions.

Comment: "I would like r to be a variable" -  It *is* a variable. "However, when I print r I don't get a .py file" - because it's a string, not a file.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(r.content)`? You'd have to hope that the repo's owner doesnt insert malicious code into that file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: Unfortunately it gives an error: >>> ast.literal_eval(r.content)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 105, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 104, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 78, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 69, in _convert_num
    _raise_malformed_node(node)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 66, in _raise_malformed_node
    raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')                 ValueError: malformed node or string: b'colors = {\r\n\r\n    "1234": {\r\n        "shade": [1, 2, 3],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is Python code, not just a string literal, use `exec`, but be aware if the code is malicious it will be executed:

```py
text = 'colors = {\r\n\r\n    "1234": {\r\n        "shade": [1, 2, 3]}\r\n}\r\n'
exec(text)
print(colors['1234']['shade'])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @enten77 You ran the *exact* code above?  It works.

Comment: Yes, it works very well for "text = 'colors = ...", but when I try to apply it to my data (r.text) it doesn't work, unfortunately. No idea why is it so.

Comment: @enten77 You would have to show the *exact* content of `r.text`.  If it is a string like `text` is above, and is *valid* Python code, it should work.  In fact it works with the `r.text` you display in your question (once I add the missing final `'` anyway).

Comment: @enten77 The error indicates the line of code with the error is using a string to index a variable, but the variable is a list and requires integers `['123']` vs. `[123]` for example.  If you show the code and the full error traceback, you can get help, perhaps in a new question.  The answer to *this* question is "use `exec` when the string is Python code".  :)